# Installing Gimp 2.8.8 from source

Tags: compiling, gimp

I am trying to install GIMP 2.8.8 and this program has a lot of dependencies. I am trying to install all of them but now I am a bit overwhelmed. I am trying to install gegl-0.2.0 it gives me this error.

```
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.28.0... 
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.38.2, but GLIB (2.32.4)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.28.0 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/.
```

*

I don't know what to do next. Can someone help me? If there is a simple way to install the latest GIMP version I would like to know that too.

I have tried to install some from the software center but the last version is 2.6.

Comment: Try installing build dependencies from Ubuntu repository, `sudo apt-get build-dep gimp` , then try build again.

Comment: See the PPA installation proposed by Jacob below : version is 2.8.10

Answer (score 2):

You can install Gimp 2.8 via ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

The plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

see also this link on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/install-gimp-286-in-ubuntu-ppa.html)

Comment: That's the best way IMO. Please note that currently (as of 23 march 2014), this PPA will install 2.8.10

Answer (score 0):

Would [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx) be enough to satisfy your image editing expectations? It is a simplified alternative to GIMP, and you can do image adjustments, add effects and so on, not very different from what you do when using Gimp. You can purge Gimp first:

```
sudo apt-get purge gimp
```

And next you can install Pinta from the Software Center or right from [the developers page](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx), after you add their repository to your software sources list and run **sudo apt-get update**.

Comment: Pinta would not work for me because I like Gimp. Pinta has not been updated since 2012. This project does not sound really convincing.

Comment: Here are the daily builds for Pinta, they even have a version for Ubuntu 14.04 : https://launchpad.net/~pinta-maintainers/+archive/pinta-daily